# Objective-C Naming components after system components

Tags: objective-c

I'd like to create a custom table view that shows cells in a linear view. I can't figure out any good name for this custom UIView class. Is it safe to name it "TableView" ?

```
TableView.h
TableView.m
```

Comment: yes. better you name it customTableView.h  and customTableView.m.

Answer (score 2):

Some general advice on naming from Apple can be found here [Coding Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-1002226-BBCJECED)

In this case you should probably add a three letter acronym - maybe your personal or company initials. I might consider `PASTableView`

---

It's worth noting that - it is good form to use prefixes as a kind of namespace to avoid naming collisions but

> Two-letter prefixes ... are reserved by Apple for use in framework classes.

Taken from [Programming With Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH10-SW4) - so use 3 letters

Answer (score 1):

It’s safe (all Apple’s classes have prefixes), but for consistency it’s a good idea to pick your own unique class name prefix and use it. See [Choose your Own Prefix on Cocoa Dev](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/ChooseYourOwnPrefix). Approaches vary.

Comment: I think it's better to keep it clean.

Comment: "all Apple’s classes have prefixes". Except when they don't: https://github.com/NikolaiRuhe/UnprefixedFrameworkClasses

Comment: Whoa, nice catch! One more reason to prefix everything.

Comment: I should be informed when a name clashes right?

Comment: @NickKeroulis Yes, you should. But you aren't.

Answer (score 1):

(So you decided to ask a question about what to name your `UITableView`... Awesome...?)

But to answer your question. There is no problem naming it `TableView.h/.m` but I would really recommend naming it something else. Such as `AwesomeQuestionTableView.h/.m` or something...

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hahahahahhahahah It's actually what bothers me most than anything else the past 2 days.

Comment: Sorry for accidental upvote.